# Semmle CodeQL CLI: "QL dataset is not compatible with the QL"

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

This error occurs anytime I run a query on a JavaScript project from CLI.

**Query**

```
codeql analyze U:\dev\test\Website-CodeQL-DB U:\codeql-home\ql\javascript\ql\src\Declarations\AnyTest.ql --format=csv --output=codeql-analyse\codeql-resultate.csv
```

**Message**

```
A fatal error occurred: This QL dataset is not compatible with the QL library U:\codeql-home\ql\javascript\ql\src\Declarations\A-Test.ql uses. Perhaps the dataset needs to be upgraded?
```

Has anyone an idea where this may come from?

Comment: I suspect a problem with your CodeQL installation.

Answer (score 2):

The libraries you are using are probably newer than the database so they are not directly compatible.

You should be able to upgrade the database using `codeql database upgrade U:\dev\test\Website-CodeQL-DB` to upgrade the database to be compatible with the new libraries.